# Error installing node-postgres on Amazon Linux. Missing pg_config.h file

Tags: linux, node.js, postgresql, amazon-ec2, node-postgres

This error seems common on windows boxes, but my Amazon Linux EC2 instance is throwing this error when I `npm install pg`:

```
../src/binding.cc:1:23: fatal error: pg_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pg_config.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/macros/test/stateHash/node_modules/pg/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.4.82-69.112.amzn1.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/macros/test/stateHash/node_modules/pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I'm on **Amazon Linux 2014.03**, and it's a micro instance running **node 0.10.28**.

**Postgres 9.2.7** is installed from the Amazon repos.  Specifically, the `postgresql9*` packages.

On a fresh `updatedb`, `locate pg_config` returns

```
/usr/bin/pg_config
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/pg_config-9.2.mo
/usr/share/man/man1/pg_config.1.gz
```

But `locate pg_config.h` returns nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `postgresql9`, `postgresql9-libs`, and `postgresql9-server` were installed by default, but not `postgresql9-devel`.

The header files required by `node-postgres` are in the missing development package.  The following steps fixed my problem:

1. Remove the `node-postgres` directory:

   `$ rm -rf node_modules/pg`
2. Install the postgres development package from the repos (*match your version carefully - the Amazon repos are a mess when it comes to postgres*):

   `$ sudo yum install postgresql9-devel`
3. Reinstall `node-postgres` (I'm doing it locally, you might be using the `-g` option):

   `$ npm install pg`

The `pg_config.h` file should be there, so the installation should work fine!

Comment: Can't believe this doesn't have more upvotes. Solved my problem.